# Selection of multiple UITextViews at once

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextview

I have multiple `UITableViewCell`s in a table view each with a selectable `UITextView`. However, when selecting, I can only select the text in each individual cell. Is it possible to select all of the text in each cell at once?

Answer (score 0):

No its not possible in iOS. At least not through UItableView. U can create multiple UITextview then u can call

```
 textView.selectAll(nil)
```